# $ x^2+y^2+z^2=k(xy+yz+zx) $

Tags: elementary-number-theory

Let

$A $ be a set of all positive integers so that if $ n\in A $ then $n-1$ has at least one prime divisor $p\equiv 2( mod 3)$ such that $v_p(n-1)$ is odd and let
$B$ be a set of all positive integers so that if $n\in B$ then $n+2$ has at least one prime divisor $p\equiv 2( mod 3)$ such that $v_p(n+2)$ is odd.

Let $k$ be a positive integer that does not belong to neither $A $ nor $B$.

Prove that the equation

$$ x^2+y^2+z^2=k(xy+yz+zx) $$

has a solution in positive integers.

Comment: Strange collection of conditions. Have you tested this for all $n$ up to whatever? Where does this question come from?

Comment: "Some examples say yes...." How many examples? A thousand? A million? Is there a proof written down somewhere that there are no nontrivial solutions for $n$ in those sets? Is there a proof that there's a solution, if you don't restrict to positive integers? The more you tell people, the easier it will be for someone to help you.

Comment: No, I didnt check thousand examples.

Comment: What then? Three examples?

Comment: http://www.artofproblemsolving.com/community/c6h1064861p4622154

Comment: n=5 : (3,5,41) , n=14: (2,3,71),

Comment: So to somplify the condition: $n$ is an integer such that for both $n-2$ and $n+1$ all primes $\equiv2 \pmod 3$ occur in even power. I suppose that menas thet $n-2$ and $n+1$ are norms in $\mathbb Z[\rho]$.

Comment: The significance of $n-1$ and $n+2$ (sign error in my last comment) may arise from $(x+y+z)^2=(n+2)(xy+xz+yz)$ and $(x-y)^2+(y-z)^2+(z-x)^2=2(n-1)(xy+yz+xz)$.